# Change UIActivityViewContoller icon order

Tags: ios, uiactivityviewcontroller

I have implemented a UIActivityViewController which is working with different data per activity type. However, I would like to change the order that the icons are displayed. Is this possible?

I have currently:

Mail, Message, Twitter and Facebook (in that order)

but would like to change it to:

Facebook, Twitter, Mail and Message.

Any pointers greatly appreciated!

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This might be possible. By default, there is no factory method of changing the order in which UIActivities appear. However, you might be able to use the controller's `excludedActivityTypes` property to exclude every activity.

This will be a painful process, but from there, you can create new UIActivity subclasses for every service you wanted, including the ones originally build in (this isn't optimal I know). Then you can pass all these newly created UIActivities back to the controller upon installation by adding them to an array and passing them as an argument to `applicationActivities:` in the controller's init method.

I can't say this with 100% certainty, but I believe the activities added to this array will show up in order.